# How to pass a script-file to sed as a heredoc?

Tags: here-document

This converts 'a' to 'A'.

```
sed 's/a/A/g' <(echo "foobar")
foobAr
```

This supplies the commands necessary to make each vowel upper-case:

```
$ cat << EOF
s/a/A/g
s/e/E/g
s/i/I/g
s/o/O/g
s/u/U/g
EOF
```

What I'm trying to do, is to extend the first example so as to make upper case each vowel, and using a here doc, as in the second example. Any suggestion?

Man:

> sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
>
> -f script-file, --file=script-file
> add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-` with `sed -f` to indicate that the script should be read from standard input:

```
$ cat << EOF | sed -f - <(echo foobar)
s/a/A/g
s/e/E/g
s/i/I/g
s/o/O/g
s/u/U/g
EOF
fOObAr
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `tr` is the appropriate solution:

```
$ echo foobar | tr [aeiou] [AEIOU]
fOObAr
```

Comment: More elegant, but this was more a case of reminding myself of some basics than...

Comment: If you use this method, you'd want to quote `[aeiou]` and `[AEIOU]` unless globbing is disabled in your shell

Comment: @Erwann I wondered if that might be the case…